# How to setup an EV Certificate a node.js server

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I've received four files from Comodo:

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
COMODORSAExtendedValidationSecureServerCA.crt
mydomain.crt
```

This is my first time setting up a https server.

I know that I have to put on parameters that is passed to `https.createServer` but my problem is I don't know which one is the correct property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server certificate is set as `cert`, whereas your CA certificates are set under `ca`:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    https = require('https');

var cfg = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/privatekey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/mydomain.crt'), // PEM format
  ca: [
    fs.readFileSync('/path/to/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt'), // PEM format
    fs.readFileSync('/path/to/COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt'), // PEM format
    fs.readFileSync('/path/to/COMODORSAExtendedValidationSecureServerCA.crt') // PEM format
  ]
};

https.createServer(cfg, function(req, res) {
  // ...
}).listen(443);
```

Or you can use just `pfx` if you have your `key`, `cert`, and `ca` files all bundled into a single PFX/PKCS12-formatted file.

Comment: i got these file files any help 
`AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt,
ComodoUTNSGCCA.crt,
EssentialSSLCA_2.crt,
UTNAddTrustSGCCA.crt
STAR_wsicloud_com.crt`

Comment: This doesn't answer initial question. He has no key nor pem file.