# SSL certificates for a Node.Js / Express app in Webfaction?

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, ssl-certificate, webfaction

I'm running my express / node.js app on a webfaction server and want to install the SSL certificates I received from Comodo... I usually self-generated two files - private and public - on my local server, but for my site I generated external ones and they sent me 4

```
Root CA Certificate - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
Your EssentialSSL Certificate - website_com.crt
```

Do you know what I should do with those if what I need to write in my app.js instead of `????`?

```
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(????)
    cert: fs.readFileSync(????)
     ca: fs.readFileSync(????)
 };
```

Thank you!

PS I thought you have to `cat` some files together, but which ones you think of the ones above?

Answer (score 1):

Your `options` would need to look something like this:

```
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/yourprivatekey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/website_com.crt'),
    ca: [
        fs.readFileSync('/path/to/COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt'),
        fs.readFileSync('/path/to/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt')
    ]
};
```

You do not need to add `AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt` to your ca list as all browsers should have the root.

Similar question: [How to setup EV Certificate with nodejs server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306763/how-to-setup-ev-certificate-with-nodejs-server)

Comment: This doesn't answer initial question, how to get PEM file?